# Why 'scan' reads multiple lines

Tags: ruby, regex

My test configuration file(test_config.conf) looks as below

```
[DEFAULT]
system_name=
#test

flag=true
```

I want to read this and scan the value for key `"system_name"`, with the expected  output `nil`. I could have used config parser to read the contents, but using `scan` is my requirement.

I did:

```
File.read
```

- Scan: `file_data.scan(/^#{each}\s*=\s*(?!.*#)\s*(.*)/)`
- Regex: `^system_name\s*=\s*(?!.*#)\s*(.*)$`

I used `(?!.*#)` to ignore the values that start with `#`.

It returns `#test`. Could someone help me understand why it does so, and how I can change my regex to make it work as expected?

Comment: What kind of environment are you in where you know a better way to do it (config parser) but feel like you don't have that as an option?

Comment: `\s` is equivalent to `[ \t\r\n\f\v]`, so it also matches newline characters. Try a more restrictive character class like `[ \t]` to match non-newline whitespace.

Comment: BTW, what value is `system_name = foo # bar` (in a single line) supposed to return – '`foo'` or `'foo # bar'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is another case of how backtracking confuses regex users. `(?!.*#)` negative lookahead must match a location that is not immediately followed with `#`.  Since the preceding pattern part can match the string in various ways, once failed, the regex engine retries the quantified subpatterns. So, in your case, `\s*` matches 0 or more whitespaces. Once the regex engine matched all the whitespaces after `=`, it finds `#` - and fails. Then backtracks: tries to match zero whitespaces. And finds out that there is no `#` after `=`. And succeeds.

Use a possessive quantifier with `\s*+` to disallow backtracking:

```
^system_name\s*=\s*+(?!#)(.*)$
                   ^
```

See the [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/SJrwiDMVUK). So, the lookahead will only be run once after all the 0+ whitespaces are matched. If it fails to match, the whole match will be failed right away.

Another way is to use `[^\s#]` negated character class:

```
^system_name\s*=\s*([^\s#].*)$
                   ^^^^^^^
```

See another [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/3rAIeWqydo)

Here, `[^\s#]` will only match a char that is not a whitespace, nor `#`, and then `.*` will match any 0+ chars other than line break chars.

**As per the feedback inside comments**, the structure of the input may be rather loose, and a key=value can follow the `system_name` line. In that case, you also need to make sure the text you capture does not actually start with some word chars followed with `=` sign:

```
/^system_name\s*=\s*+(?!#|\w+=)(.*)$/
```

See [this Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/VqaCdlQOZz)

**Full pattern details**:

- `^` - start of a line
- `system_name` - a literal substring
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
- `=` - an equal sign
- `\s*+` - 0 or more whitespaces with no backtracking into the pattern due to `*+` possessive quantifier
- `(?!#|\w+=)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if the `#` or 1+ word chars and then `=` are found immediately to the right of the current location (that is right after the 0+ whitespaces)
- `(.*)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars up to the end of the line
- `$` - end of a line.

Comment: I changed the input configuration file to something as below and it failed partially                                                                                       
    ```system_name = 
    flag=true```

Comment: Please share  a Rubular fiddle link. What do you expect to get?

Comment: If I give input as shown in http://rubular.com/r/588LDRpSrE it shouldn't display anything in match group since flag=true is another key-value pair in that configuration file

Comment: Yep, it did work. Trying to understand the supplied regex